# Why is a class not an "instanceof" its parent class?

Tags: coffeescript

Coffeescript code:

```
class Animal
  constructor: (@name) ->

  move: (meters) ->
    alert @name + " moved #{meters}m."

class Snake extends Animal
  move: ->
    alert "Slithering..."
    super 5

alert Snake instanceof Animal
```

Here is [a link](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Animal%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20%28%40name%29%20-%3E%0A%0A%20%20move%3A%20%28meters%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20alert%20%40name%20%2B%20%22%20moved%20%23%7Bmeters%7Dm.%22%0A%0Aclass%20Snake%20extends%20Animal%0A%20%20move%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20alert%20%22Slithering...%22%0A%20%20%20%20super%205%0A%0Aalert%20Snake%20instanceof%20Animal).

I really think this result true.
And my reason is this `__extends` method in compiled JavaScript:

```
__extends = function (child, parent) {
    for(var key in parent) {
        if(__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key];
    }function ctor() {
        this.constructor = child;
    }
    ctor.prototype = parent.prototype;
    child.prototype = new ctor();
    child.__super__ = parent.prototype;
    return child;
};
```

`child.prototype.prototype` is parent.

Can someone tell me why?
And I know below is true:

```
alert new Snake('a') instanceof Animal
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Snake` is a subclass of `Animal`:

```
class Snake extends Animal
```

That means that `Snake` (a "class") is actually an instance of `Function`, not `Animal`. A `Snake` object, on the other hand, would be an instance of `Animal`:

```
alert Snake instanceof Function     # true
alert (new Snake) instanceof Animal # true
```

And if you try to get a `Snake` instance to move:

```
(new Snake('Pancakes')).move()
```

you'll see that the right methods are called.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/3NmCZ/1/